# Vscode "next search result" shortcut does not work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, shortcut

When I use the shortcut associated with "search.action.focusNextSearchResult" in vscode while searching something nothing happens.

This action is initially associated with F4 which is also used for other shortcuts. I thought it may be the problem so I reassigned it to an unused shortcut but it did not help.

I am using the extension "Emacs Friendly Keymap" (don't know if it can cause the problem).

Do you know how I could make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shortcut, used to go to the next search result, only works **in a search editor**.  It has these context keys:

`hasSearchResult || inSearchEditor`

Are you using it in a separate search editor?  It does work there.  Here is one way to open a `Search Editor`:

[image: open a search editor]

If you are using the Find widget then use either of these:

<kbd>Enter</kbd> when focus is still in the Find widget or <kbd>F3</kbd> when focus is in the editor.

If you are doing a search across files, then just a <kbd>downarrow</kbd> will go to the next result.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know what the search editor was. Shift+F3 works to find the previous but F3 does not :(. I also tried to reassign it without success